# Determining which set is larger

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have the following problem, which is quite basic and the right answer is clear, but there is something going wrong in computation that I cannot determine.  Consider the following:

*Problem:* Let $S$ be a set of 500 two digit numbers, where each two digit number is repeated five times, that is:
$$
S = \{00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,...,99, 99, 99, 99, 99\}
$$
Then, this is a set of 500 elements where each element is repeated five times, so there are
$$
\frac{500!}{100\cdot 5!}
$$
*distinguishable permutations* of this set.  Furthermore, for each of these distinguishable permutations, we can correspond it to a 1000 digit number in the natural way, by joining each of the 500 two digit numbers in a sequence.  Then $00000000001111111111\cdots 9999999999$ would be one such 500 digit number for example.

But there are 1000 digit numbers that cannot be obtained by the above method: for example the 1000 digit number of all 9's cannot be obtained since $S$ only has five 99 elements, so it is clear that the set of all 1000 digit numbers is larger than the set of numbers constructed as above from distinguishable permuations of $S$.

But there are $10^{1000}$ 1000 digit numbers, so why is it that the following inequality holds?
$$
\frac{500!}{100\cdot 5!} > 10^{1000}
$$
As this would imply the set of numbers obtained from the distinguishable permutations is bigger.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Then, this is a set of 500 elements where each element is repeated five times, so there are
$$
\frac{500!}{100\cdot 5!}
$$
*distinguishable permutations* of this set."

No, There are $$
\frac{500!}{(5!)^{100}}
$$
distinguishable permutations of this set.
This is because there are $5!$ ways for the ones to be permuted and then for each of those there are $5!$ ways for the twos to be permuted so $(5!)^2$ ways for the ones and twos to be permuted and this repeats until we get the answer above. This is less than $10^{1000}$ so it works (By a python script it has 927 digits)

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was making a dumb mistake like that!